# Can some one please tell me why only one button works? its always the top one but never both

Tags: android

I would like to know how to get two buttons to work on one activity iv tried everything only one works  id really be thankful if someone can help me i got my code just cant post it here

Comment: private void configurebutton1() {
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

Toast.makeText(MMW2.this, "LOADING", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

startActivity(new Intent(MMW2.this, MMW.class));

Comment: Please post all your code, including XML files, as part of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:

```
private void configurebutton1() {
  Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
  btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      Toast.makeText(MMW2.this, "LOADING", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      startActivity(new Intent(MMW2.this, MMW.class)); 
    }
  }
}
private void configurebutton2() {
  Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
  btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      Toast.makeText(MMW2.this, "LOADING #2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      startActivity(new Intent(MMW2.this, MMW3.class)); 
    }
  }
}
```

here `R.id.button1` and `R.id.button2` is referred to the `Button` ids on your xml file. and `MMW3.class` is assumed to be another class you probably wanted to call on your second button.
and on your `onCreate` method don't forget to call these methods:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
  super(savedInstance);
  setContentView(R.layout.mwm2);
  configurebutton1();
  configurebutton2();
  ....
}
```

Comment: No that didnt help is there anyway that I can send you the coding or anything....?

Comment: @user3127827 you should edit your post, and put your code there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure you have listeners for each Button

If your Buttons are created in the xml and not dynamically.

Add this to the Button xml

```
    android:onClick="funtionName"
```

And then in MainActivity or whichever activity

```
public void funtionName(View v) {
}
```